# Can &Some(_) in vec.iter() { .. } compile?

Tags: rust

I tried to run the following code snippet:

```
let a = &[Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None, Some(4)];

let mut sum = 0;
for &Some(x) in a.iter() {
    sum += x;
}

assert_eq!(sum, 1+2+3+4);
```

The compiler replied with:

```
about_loops.rs:39:9: 43:18 error: non-exhaustive patterns: None not covered
about_loops.rs:39         for &Some(x) in a.iter() {
about_loops.rs:40             sum += x;
about_loops.rs:41         } 
about_loops.rs:42 
about_loops.rs:43         assert_eq!(sum, 1+2+3+4);
error: aborting due to previous error
make: *** [all] Error 101
```

Can I make such a construct compile for a for loop without using a match expression as suggested by luke and hobbs? Or is this error message misleading?
It does not seem so given the grammar definition of for.

```
for_expr : "for" pat "in" expr '{' block '}' ;
```

I'm on:

```
rustc 0.11.0-pre-nightly (6291955 2014-05-19 23:41:20 -0700)
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
```

To clarify: How expressive is the 'pat' portion of for_expr? This is not specified under http://doc.rust-lang.org/rust.html#for-expressions in contrast to the definition under http://doc.rust-lang.org/rust.html#match-expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern of a `for` loop essentially has the same restrictions as a `let`: it has to be irrefutable, that is, it can't ever fail to match.

Examples of irrefutable patterns are `&`, tuples, structs and single-variant enums. Other patterns (like multivariant enums or literals) aren't guaranteed to always match, since the type allows for values that aren't covered by the pattern.

The `for` construct is essentially a macro that desugars as follows (it desugars in the same pass as macros are expanded, you can see it manually running rustc with `--pretty expanded`):

```
for <pattern> in <iter_expression> {
    <code>
}

// becomes

match &mut <iter_expression> { // match to guarantee data lives long enough
    it => {
        loop {
            match it.next() {
                None => break,
                Some(<pattern>) => { <code> }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is a normal `match`, i.e. the arms have to be exhaustive (cover every possibility), and so if `<pattern>` is just `&Some(_)`, then the `Some(&None)` possibility isn't covered.

(The `Some` arm is essentially equivalent to `Some(value) => { let <pattern> = value; ...`. Thinking about it now, this might actually be a desugaring that gives better error messages: I filed [#14390](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/14390).)

Answer (score 1):

The `Some` is a type in an enum. The `Option` enum has two types, `Some(T)` and `None`. Your code assumes that `a.iter()` always is `Some(T)`, and never checks for `None`. To add in the check, you can use an `match`. Something like this:

```
let a = &[Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None, Some(4)];

let mut sum = 0;
for &j in a.iter() {
  match j {
    Some(x) => sum += x,
    None => ()
  }
}

assert_eq!(sum, 1+2+3+4);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I agree that this is a way to express the same code, and in a more clear way. But my question is if the &Some(_) in the 'pat' section of the for loop gives meaning. It would be a short-hand for what you suggested.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this as I am still learning rust: The pat is the pattern that rust tries to match to. This match must be exhaustive for your code to compile. This ensures no errors. For the option case however, I can see something like could be used shorthand. I am guessing a macro of some kind could create something similar, but I am unsure. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`for` is binding each element in `a` to the pattern `&Some(x)` — so when the first element of `a` is `&Some(1)`, `x` becomes 1. But `None` doesn't match the pattern `&Some(x)` so the binding can't succeed. Rust infers from the literal values that the type of `a` is actually `Option` (the type that encompasses either `Some(_)` or `None`) and that your pattern doesn't cover all of the possibilities. Instead of waiting for runtime to tell you it doesn't know what to do, it throws an error at compile-time instead.

From what little Rust I know (mostly having read the tutorial) I think you need to do something like:

```
for &thing in a.iter() {
    match thing {
        Some(x) => sum += x
        None => /* do nothing */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works as well:

```
use std::iter::AdditiveIterator;

fn main() {

    let a = &[Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None, Some(4)];
    let sum = a.iter().filter_map(|x| *x).sum();
    assert_eq!(sum, 1+2+3+4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
let sum = a.iter().fold(0, |s, e| s + e.unwrap_or(0));
```